# Save data using Kitura - Swift

Tags: swift, swift3, couchdb, kitura

I am doing a POC to save data into CouchDB using IBM' Kitura application. I am able to upload some data in CouchDB using scripts and able to fetch and send that using a web API.

Similarly, I want another API that accepts data in JSON format and save in Couch DB.

Any guidance will be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Have you taken a look at the Kitura-CouchDB package available here: https://github.com/IBM-Swift/Kitura-CouchDB

It also provides a usage sample case.

Answer (score 1):

You can also take a look at our TodoList example using CouchDB (or Cloudant) databases.

https://github.com/IBM-Swift/TodoList-CouchDB/

```
      let couchDBClient = CouchDBClient(connectionProperties: connectionProperties)
            let database = couchDBClient.database(databaseName)
            let x = JSON(json)
            print("JSON: \(x.rawString())")
            database.create(JSON(json)) {

   }
```